# How to use filter for multiple fields?

Tags: angular

I have this method:

```
  search(event) {
        let uniqueArray = [];
        this.autocompletedata.filter((entry) => {
            console.log('entryyyy', entry);
                this.results = entry['items'].filter(a => this.showFilter == 1 ? a['item'].startsWith(event.query) :  
                   this.showFilter == 2 ? a['service'].startsWith(event.query) : 
                   this.showFilter == 3 ? a['phoneNum'].startsWith(event.query) : false );
                   const curr: string[] = this.results.map(data => data.item ? data.item : 
                    data.service ? data.service : data.phoneNum ? data.phoneNum : false );
                    this.results = curr.filter((x, i, a) => x && a.indexOf(x) === i);
        });

       console.log(this.results);

    }
```

So what i want to check if showFilter is 1 to use a['item'].startsWith(event.query) this and if fiiter is 2 to use a['service'].startsWith(event.query) and so on..

Comment: *Where i have multiple fields that i want to check and also map them*: could you please provide a clearer explanation on what you want to achieve? With example inputs and example outputs?

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some example filtering code here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

It includes information on filtering using multiple criteria:

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
          product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 || 
          product.description.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments to your question, it's difficult to make out exactly what you need from just the code you posted. But hopefully this example will get you on the right track.

Or check out the blog post for a few more examples.

Comment: thats the thing i need :D